# How to change the background of the body with fade-In effect

Tags: jquery

now i want to change the background of the body with fade-In effect.

```js
var imgSrcs = ["img/bg1.jpg","img/bg2.jpg","img/bg3.jpg","img/bg4.jpg","img/bg5.jpg"];
setInterval(function() {
  $("body").css("background-image", "url(" + imgSrcs[imgSrcs.push(imgSrcs.shift()) - 1] + ")");
}, 3000);
```

have this code and it works fine,but i want to add fade in effect while it change.

Comment: Read up on jquery chaining. http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp. You can chain multiple methods together. So all you would need to add is the .fadeIn() method to the end of your $("body") chain.

Comment: @TylerEvans i tried it but it doesn't work because it fade out the full content of the body .. i want to change the background not the full page

Comment: Yep that's a good point. looks like theres a good answer below anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` on a absolute positioned mock background

```js
var imgSrcs =[
    "http://placehold.it/700x200/&text=bg2.jpg",
    "http://placehold.it/700x200/&text=bg3.jpg",
    "http://placehold.it/700x200/&text=bg4.jpg",
    "http://placehold.it/700x200/&text=bg5.jpg",
    "http://placehold.it/700x200/&text=bg1.jpg"
];

$('.background').fadeIn(1000, animateBackground());

function animateBackground() {
    
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        
        var url = imgSrcs[imgSrcs.push(imgSrcs.shift()) - 1];
        
        $('.background').delay(1000).fadeOut(1000, function(){
                
            $(this).css("background-image", "url(" + url + ")")
                
        }).fadeIn(1000, animateBackground())

    });
}
```

```css
.background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: -9999;
    display: none;
    background-image: url('http://placehold.it/700x200/&text=bg1.jpg');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="background"></div>

<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

Alternatively, You can use CSS3 transitions

```js
var imgSrcs =[
    "http://placehold.it/700x200/&text=bg1.jpg",
    "http://placehold.it/700x200/&text=bg2.jpg",
    "http://placehold.it/700x200/&text=bg3.jpg",
    "http://placehold.it/700x200/&text=bg4.jpg",
    "http://placehold.it/700x200/&text=bg5.jpg"
];

setInterval(function() { 
    $("body").css("background-image", "url(" + imgSrcs[imgSrcs.push(imgSrcs.shift()) - 1] + ")");
}, 1000);
```

```css
body {
    -webkit-transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks :) it works fine but looks like sliding with the width and heights of the background .. can we do it fadein and then fadeout